# Dart typecast dynamic extension

Tags: flutter, dart

I wonder if it is possible to write an extension function that will cast dynamic to Class of my choice, so that I may have fields suggestions in my IDE.

I've tried somethings like this:

```
extension DynamicCasting on dynamic {
  T as<T>() => this is T ? this as T : null;
}
```

but when I used it

```
class User {
  final String name;

  User(this.name);
}

...

foo[i].as<User>().
```

It still sees it as dynamic and name field isn't suggested.

Comment: does it give any runtime errors? I think its because the feature is so new that IntelliSense isn't uptp date with it.

Comment: well it actually does, it produces TypeError

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to work in [dartpad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/) I can see the expected member of the String class used in `.as<String>().` with the following snippet. So it looks like an issue in your IDE and/or your project setup.

```
void main() {
  print(1.as<String>().);
}

extension DynamicCasting on dynamic {
  T as<T>() => this is T ? this as T : null;
}
```

Comment: Could you please provide with your code beacuse for me it produces TypeError

Comment: If you are using null safety, then the above code needs to be fixed.`T? as<T>() => this is T ? this as T : null;`